# Weird DataInputStream skip behavior in GLib(Vala)

Tags: glib, vala

I am making a helper class for my .NBS(Note Block Studio song file) editor and I encountered a very weird `DataInputStream` skip behavior while coding up the part which loads .NBS files into a struct. For example, if the author name is "Wattana", it will show up as "attana" and I will have to reduce the skip to 3 bytes. Why does skipping 4 bytes before `song_author` skip the first character in the string while doing so before `song_name` does not?

(Part of codes from the helper class)

```
public static SongData to_song_data (DataInputStream data_stream) {
        // Specifications for the NBS file format can be found at https://opennbs.org/nbs
        data_stream.set_byte_order (DataStreamByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        var song_data = new SongData();

        // Note to self: a "short" is 2 bytes(16 bits) long.
        // TODO: Add error handler.
        song_data.old_version = data_stream.read_int16 ();
        song_data.version = data_stream.read_byte ();
        song_data.vanilla_intrument_count = data_stream.read_byte ();
        song_data.length = data_stream.read_int16 ();
        song_data.layer_count = data_stream.read_int16 ();
        data_stream.skip (4); // 4 bytes(32 bits) must be skipped before reading any string from an NBS file.
        song_data.song_name = data_stream.read_line ();
        data_stream.skip (3); // Not sure why 4 bytes skip doesn't work here.
        song_data.song_author = data_stream.read_line ();

        return song_data;
    }
```

Comment: Have you verified with a hex dump that the file actually contains 4 bytes there that should be skipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some error handling to get more details:

```cs
try {
    data_stream.skip (4);
} catch (IOError error) {
    print (@"error.message\n");
}
```

Also note that [`.skip()`](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.InputStream.skip.html) returns the number of bytes skipped or -1 on error. So you can test for that in your debugging.

There is also the question of why are you skipping? The [NBS format specification](https://opennbs.org/nbs) states that 'Strings consist of a 32-bit integer, and then that many bytes for the characters'. From what I can tell you are skipping the length integer, whereas you should be using that as a counter for the loop to read the following characters in the file, then add a zero byte at the end to make it a Vala string.